# How to ensure data does not remain in RAM in USB-connected Fingerprint reader

Tags: ram, fingerprint

I sniff RAM memory for fingerprint data received from Futronic fingerprint scanner. Is there security mechanism to ensure sensitive data is not stored or theft ?

Comment: FS26E Futronic Fingerprint reader has a security mechanism called Encrypted USB communication.